# program goes in infinite loop when eof is used

Tags: c, file, eof

Below Program is compiled successfully with no error but it goes in **Infinite Loop**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr;
    char s;
    ptr = fopen("checkit.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
        perror("Cause of error is: ");
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            s = fgetc(ptr);
            if (s == EOF)
                break;
            printf("%c", s);
        }
        fclose(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But compilor shows following warning.

```
warning: comparison of constant -1 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
                        if (s == EOF)
```

I have write same program without using EOF then it compile and run successfully and open the file.
Below is the working program without any error or warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr;
    char s;
    ptr = fopen("checkit.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
        perror("Cause of error is: ");
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            s = fgetc(ptr);
            if (feof(ptr))
                break;
            printf("%c", s);
        }
        fclose(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I am unable to understand that what is the reason that EOF is not working**

Comment: Do not use `char, unsigned char, signed char` to declare `s`.  Use `int s;`.  `fgetc()` typically returns 257 different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's implementation-defined if `char` is a signed or unsigned integer type.

If it's unsigned then `EOF` will actually become `255` when the `char` value is promoted to an `int`. And `255 != -1` (`-1` is the value of `EOF`).

This is the reason that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`** and not a `char`. So the result can be directly comparable to the `int` value `EOF`.

It seems that on your system `char` is unsigned, so to solve your problem, define `s` as an `int` variable instead:

```
int s;
```

Comment: Got it. Thaks a lot. Now, it's working in both conditions when I use **signed char** or **int**. But I want to know that when we directly use **char** in program without specifying signed or unsigned then what is understand by the compiler?

Comment: Some programmer dude, " then EOF will actually become 255 when the char value is promoted to an int" i--> not quite.  `s` is 255 before the promotion.  `s = fgetc(ptr);` leads to `EOF` being saved as 255 as `s` is an _unsigned_ `char`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `char` in your environment is an unsigned type shorter than `int`.

On the other hand, `EOF` is a negative value.

Value of unsigned value will never be negative.

[`fgetc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns `int`. You should use `int`, not `char`, for storing its result.

Comment: Got it. Now its working. But I want to know if we don't specify **signed** or **unsigned** of **char** in the program then what type will be taken by compiler? or it's depend upon environment I am using?

Comment: @Suraj "or it's depend upon environment I am using?" --> Yes, implementation dependent.  Compiler's sometimes offer an option to select _signed_ or _unsigned_ `char`.